# Why does Windows Defender apparently only return exit codes "0" or "2", but never 1?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-defender

When I run the command `"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"`, it outputs the information for the command. One part says this:

> ```
>  Return code is
>  0    if no malware is found or malware is successfully remediated and no additional user action is required
>  2    if malware is found and not remediated or additional user action is required to complete remediation or there is error in scanning.  Please check >History for more information.
> ```

So it can have return codes 0 or 2, but not 1? Why did they (apparently) skip 1? Is this because 1 is traditionally supposed to be for an "actual error", and they only used 0 to mean "no malware found" because this is "expected behaviour" from binaries from all OSes for decades?

That would make sense, but you'd think they would at least list `1` if it can be returned sometimes?

Comment: Only Microsoft will be able to answer this question.

Comment: You would have to contact Microsoft to determine the reason for the return codes that were chosen.  We can't possibly know the reason MpCmdRun.exe only returns `0` or `2` only what those return codes mean (which isn't the subject of this question).

Comment: Here when common errors occur in cmd and the program terminates then they usually return error code 1. Microsoft, I think, didn't want MpCmdRun.exe will return error code 1. This is because how the executable was programmed.