# Getting functional output from Windows Defender over command line

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-defender

Writing a powershell script for one of our automated processes, and I'm delighted to see I can use MpCmdRun for the scanning. Only problem I've found is, when running it against a file, the only output is the following:

```
Scan starting...
Scan finished.
Scanning C:\Users\cooldude\QuestionableFile.pdf.exe found no threats.
```

I would have wanted to perform some series of actions based on whether or not `QuestionableFile.pdf.exe` was found to be a threat, so some usable output other than `found no threats` would have been useful.

Other than writing something that'll parse the last few characters of this output (found no threats), what could I do? Does MpCmdRun.exe terminate with some code to indicate if it's a good file or otherwise?

Comment: It sets `errorlevel` to 0 if no virus so check for `errorlevel` > 0 should do the trick.

Comment: See [command line - Why does Windows Defender apparently only return exit codes "0" or "2", but never 1? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1565589/why-does-windows-defender-apparently-only-return-exit-codes-0-or-2-but-neve)